# composer require branch are rejected by your constraint

Tags: composer-php, symfony4

symfony 4.1

composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

removing "minimum-stability": "dev", don`t have sitation.

```
 "Mea/TemplateEditorBundle": "dev-v4@dev",
```

The requested package mea/templateeditorbundle v4@dev as dev-master exists as Mea/TemplateEditorBundle[dev-master, 3.0, v2.8, dev-2@dev, dev-v3@dev, dev-v4@dev] but these are rejected by your constraint.

```
 "Mea/TemplateEditorBundle": "v4@dev as dev-master",
```

The requested package mea/templateeditorbundle v4@dev as dev-master exists as Mea/TemplateEditorBundle[dev-master, 3.0, v2.8, dev-2@dev, dev-v3@dev, dev-v4@dev] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not